# Add multiple continuously rotated images to the image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-view

[image]

hi guys as title,
I want to add multiple images(red fan) that are continuously rotated on an existing image (about 10~40),I have implemented it by using View "onDraw", but the system resource consumption is very serious, the CPU usage is 30%~40%.

Is there any better way? Like using a game framework or surfaceview?

Thanks in advance.

onDraw

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int j=1;
        final int viewHeight =610;
        for (final Fan fan : mFans) {

            j = j+1;
            final float fanSize = 8;

//            // Save the current canvas state
            final int save = canvas.save();
            if(XArray.size()>0){
                y = (int) YArray.get(j);
                x = (int) XArray.get(j);
            // Move the canvas to the center of the fan
            canvas.translate(x,  y);

            // Rotate the canvas based on how far the fan has moved
            final float progress = (fan.y + fanSize) / viewHeight;
            canvas.rotate(360 * progress);

            // Prepare the size and alpha of the drawable
            final int size = (int) fanSize;
            mDrawable.setBounds(-size, -size, size, size);

            // Draw the fan to the canvas
            mDrawable.draw(canvas);

            // Restore the canvas to it's previous position and rotation
            canvas.restoreToCount(save);
        }}
    }
```

onAttachedToWindow()

```
 @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        mTimeAnimator = new TimeAnimator();
        mTimeAnimator.setTimeListener(new TimeAnimator.TimeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator animation, long totalTime, long deltaTime) {
                if (!isLaidOut()) {
                    // Ignore all calls before the view has been measured and laid out.
                    return;
                }
                updateState(deltaTime);
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        mTimeAnimator.start();
    }
 /**
     * Pause the animation if it's running
     */
    public void pause() {
        if (mTimeAnimator != null && mTimeAnimator.isRunning()) {
            // Store the current play time for later.
            mCurrentPlayTime = mTimeAnimator.getCurrentPlayTime();
            mTimeAnimator.pause();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resume the animation if not already running
     */
    public void resume() {
        if (mTimeAnimator != null && mTimeAnimator.isPaused()) {
            mTimeAnimator.start();
            // Why set the current play time?
            // TimeAnimator uses timestamps internally to determine the delta given
            // in the TimeListener. When resumed, the next delta received will the whole
            // pause duration, which might cause a huge jank in the animation.
            // By setting the current play time, it will pick of where it left off.
            mTimeAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(mCurrentPlayTime);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Progress the animation by moving the Fans based on the elapsed time
     * @param deltaMs time delta since the last frame, in millis
     */
    private void updateState(final float deltaMs) {
//         Converting to seconds since PX/S constants are easier to understand
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
        final float deltaSeconds = deltaMs / 1000f;
        final int viewWidth = getWidth();
        final int viewHeight = getHeight();

        for (final Fan fan : mFans) {
            // Move the Fan based on the elapsed time and it's speed
            fan.y -= fan.speed * deltaSeconds;

            // If the Fan is completely outside of the view bounds after
            // updating it's position, recycle it.
            final float size = fan.scale * mBaseSize;
//            if (fan.y + size < 0) {
//                initializeFan(fan, viewWidth, viewHeight);
//            }
        }   // long run job
            }

        }).start();



    }
```

Comment: did you use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator` / `TimeAnimator` inside your custom `View`? if so, post your code

Comment: @pskink I customized a "View" and he will redraw it on "onDraw"

Comment: did you use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator` / `TimeAnimator` inside your custom `View`?

Comment: I have TimeAnimator()